# Hide service namespace in client application

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, wcf, windows-services

I have a Dll that is referencing a Service (via adding a service reference). I plan to distribute this library internally in the company to various developers. However, I would not like them to access the service directly and would only like for to pass through my library. On one of my test client apps where I reference the dll in discussion, I see the service namespace accessible as well. Is there a way to restrict, may be have a private modifier for my service reference in the dll. Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into writing a proxy to the service instead of just Add Service Reference and obfuscating the service name in the proxy?

Comment: If there's no way of hiding the service reference, maybe your DLL could pass in a password of some sort (and you obfuscate your DLL code of course).

Comment: @SASS_Shooter I have not explored that scenario, I am new to working with services, I will update this post after I try your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out the answer to this. I wanted to update here, so it may be helpful to anyone in the future.

After adding the service reference, right click on the ServiceReference to "Configure Service Reference". In the field "Access Level For Generated Classes" - select "Internal", so it is only accessible from within this assembly.